# Cannot create a channel via API in Amio.io

Tags: facebook-messenger, amio

I'm trying to use the [Facebook createChannel API](https://docs.amio.io/v1.0/reference#facebook-messenger-channels-create-channel) but I always get an error saying either my facebook page ID or my access token is wrong. I've generated a long-lived page access token, which I've inserted as an access token, and I've set facebook page ID.

There is yet something weird in the error because it is always related to the app ID "1806054702946735" whatever I specify as facebook page ID...

Below is the response of the API:

```
  {
    "timestamp": "2018-08-17T22:03:14.818Z",
    "status": {
      "code": 400,
      "message": "Bad Request"
    },
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Error while getting long lived access token for facebook page. Check if your facebook page ID and access token are correct. Received original response: The access token does not belong to application 1806054702946735"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Can you help me through this, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably generated your `access token` for a different **FB App ID** (not for 1806054702946735 which is the shared app within Amio). There 2 ways how you can solve this:

1. [Assign your own FB app to Amio](https://docs.amio.io/docs/facebook-messenger-tutorials-custom-facebook-app) - then you can use your generated access tokens
2. Regenerate your `access token` for FB App ID 1806054702946735

**Regenerate token for 1806054702946735**

To regenerate token for Amio FB App, just set the ID in the [FB SDK init method](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart):

```
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId: '1806054702946735',
      // ...
    });
  };
```